# Unable to see code in code editor visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am unable to see the C# code in visual studio 2019. I didn't make any changes prior to this issue. I just tried updating VS but it didn't work, I also searched around for other solutions but could not find any that worked for me.
Thanks in advance.
[picture of blank VS here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbVFi.png)

Comment: Have you tried opening Solution Explorer from the View menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by opening Solution Explorer from the View menu, thanks to @Panagiotis Kanavos.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).